# Appropriate forecasting model for a huge amount of variables (updated at different, but constant intervals)?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, high-dimensional

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach a forecasting problem for a very large (several thousand) amount of variables.

Suppose there is around 1000 variables (time series). Each is updated regularly (say monthly), but at different times - for example $X_{512}$ is updated on the 17th every month, $X_{778}$ is updated on the first Monday of each month etc.

We have gathered about 60 data points for every variable (5 years). The variables are highly correlated with each other.

Of these 1000 variables, let's say we designate about a 100 as variables of interest. At any given point, we are insterested in forecasting a particular one of those 'variables of interest', and only one time period (of that particular variable) ahead. (It's not a priori known when and which one variable will need to be forecast).

One suggested idea to deal with this problem is to use a 'correlation clustering' algorithm in order to separate the 1000 variables into more manageable subsets and then deal with only the relevant subset once it's decided which variable has to be studied.

Which other methods could be used for such a problem? What general concept/technique/literature should I study in order to understand and select an appropriate model for this problem?

Comment: Given that your variables are correlated, Vector Autoregression (VAR, not to be confused with Value At Risk) might be a possibility - I just don't know whether there are implementations that can deal with several thousand time series with just 60 observations. Plus, not all your series are known until the end of the history (but you could get around that by simply forecasting those that aren't known yet). Perhaps you could give some more information as to what these time series are about?

Comment: The issue of different series being updated for the same reference period at different times is sometimes called the "jagged edge problem". You can fairly easily deal with this for any linear Gaussian state-space model (including VAR), at least. The issue of forecasting a large number of series with few observations is somewhat orthogonal and fairly difficult (simple models + regularization would be needed). Cross-validation is harder because of the release schedule; how will your "correlation clustering" deal with a highly correlated variable that comes out too late some of the time?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, note that Value-at-Risk is spelled with lower-case a, thus VaR. Once that is realized, VAR and VaR are easier to separate.

Comment: @RichardHardy: in a better world, you would be right. However, my third search result for "value at risk" spells it VAR ("or sometimes VaR"): http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/092904.asp